# Universal data model and microservices integration

Tags: data-modeling, domain-model, microservices

Since the native-cloud applications or microservices architecture requires  decentralized data model (each microservices has its own database), and [universal data model](http://www.universaldatamodels.com/) is centralized data model

So, how we have microservices architecture with universal data model patterns?

Is there any reference or implementation of universal data model and microservices?

Comment: Which "universal data model pattern" are you referring to exactly? Please provide a link.

Comment: Universal data model is unique reusable templates, or Universal Data Models see more [link](http://www.universaldatamodels.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the two concepts are **not compatible**. Using a universal data model for all of your services would clash with a couple of key ideas behind using Microservices, e.g. [Polyglot Persistence](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PolyglotPersistence.html), separate development & deployment of each service. Also, let's not forget that the "Data Model Resource Book" was last updated in 2009.

However, **if you must** combine the two approaches, e.g. because management insists on it, you can encapsulate all access to the universal data model by a dedicated service and make your other services dependent on it.

Some good thoughts on the subject can be found here: http://plainoldobjects.com/2015/09/02/does-each-microservice-really-need-its-own-database-2/

Comment: Thanks for your right answer. I'll read your mentioned references and And I hope to be effective.

Comment: am also at the same position we are using party data model with microservices and i wanted to understand best practice for same..  please share your experience if any .. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Yes to @Fritz's point -- universal data modeling and microservices are really two different concepts and are very difficult if not impossible to be used together. I would like to add that the reasoning for polyglot persistence is also because of how the data should be modeled. Microservices allow the use of different data stores that can best model the data according to their domain.

To elaborate more, I don't think it would do justice to mention microservices and data modeling but not domain driven design. From my experience, domain driven design really helps in thinking about services, their responsibilities, and their right to exist. For instance, I found it often to be the case that there are usually a collection of services that carries out a particular domain functionality. An example could be an e-commerce application that have payments, shopping carts, etc. These could be separated into different "bounded contexts" based on domain driven design terminology.

With the different bounded contexts, each microservice no longer sees the same concept in the system the same, so in effect, there is no real universal data model. The easiest example that I can think of to show this, is when you also want reporting on the metrics in the system. If the example was an ecommerce application, the notion of a transaction in the orders microservice are going to be different than transactions in a reporting service. The reporting service for instance may want to know about transactions at a sub-level such as the profit or revenue generated for a particular order instead of the particular line items in an order. However, in the perspective of the orders service, the order details such as the line items and the address of the individual that made the purchase are probably important and should be known. This should then require two different data models.

With respect to domain modeling, I may be a bit extreme but I would go as far as saying that if there are multiple services sharing the same data source, they should really be the same service; there should be only one service for a single data source. My arguments for that would be that the domain hasn't been properly modeled and that the coupling makes it different to evolve any one service if there are multiple services that relies on a single data source. The case could be that one service requires the schema of the data source to change while the other one does not but still is required to accommodate the schema change. Hope this helps!